# source not found error for android

Tags: android

I have following code:

```
if (APP_STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN"))
        {
            int i=0;

            List<Mikats> dbmessages = mdb.getAllMikats();

                for (Mikats c:dbmessages){



                    String eventTitle=c.getEventTitle();
                    String masjid=c.getMasjid();
                    if(eventTitle!=null || masjid!=null)
                    {
                    tvEventTitle.setText(eventTitle);
                    tvMasjid.setText(masjid);
                    }
                    i++;
                }               

        }
```

when control comes on:

```
tvEventTitle.setText(eventTitle);
```

It gives me source not found in eclips.

I checked eventTitle is having its string value.

i have also initialized `tvEventTitle` before in my code.

Not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: just check id for textview or post xml file here

Comment: make sure you are initializing the tvEventTitle after setcontentview

Comment: @PiyushMishra found the solution

Comment: @PiyushGupta found solution. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

I have written above code in function called localtoscreen()

and have initialized tvEventTitle after the function call.

Thats why it was problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be `setText` method visibility is not correct? Try make it public.